# finding a file in unix using wildcards in file name

Tags: file, unix, find, ksh

I have few files in a folder with name pattern in which one of the section is variable.

```
file1.abc.12.xyz
file2.abc.14.xyz
file3.abc.98.xyz
```

So the third section (numeric) in above three file names changes everyday.

Now, I have a script which does some tasks on the file data. However, before doing the work, I want to check whether the file exists or not and then do the task:

```
if(file exist) then
     //do this
fi
```

I wrote the below code using wildcard '*' in numeric section:

```
export mydir=/myprog/mydata

if[find $mydir/file1.abc.*.xyz]; then 
   # my tasks here

fi
```

However, it is not working and giving below error:

```
 [find: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Using -f instead of find does not work as well:

```
if[-f $mydir/file1.abc.*.xyz]; then
  # my tasks here

fi
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I am using korn shell.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using spaces before the unix keywords...

For e.g. "if[-f" should actually be " if [ -f" with spaces before and after the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in file1.abc.*.xyz ; do
    # use $i here ...
done
```